# Performance Report Generation

Tags: performance, jmeter, report

I'm a performance engineer and predominantly use the JMeter tool for testing. report generation exports the aggregate results and calculates other stuff and prepared the consolidated re-PT report. Sometime will generate graphs from jtl file also. if there is any option to generate a report a high-level report. Any open source tool available for report generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JMeter supports dashboard report generation to get graphs and statistics from a test plan.

[JMeter Dashboard Reporting Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

> The dashboard generator is a modular extension of JMeter. Its default behavior is to read and process samples from CSV files to generate HTML files containing graph views. It can generate the report at end of a load test or on demand.

Generation from an existing sample CSV log file:

```
jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>
```

Generation after load test:

```
jmeter -n -t <test JMX file> -l <test log file> -e -o <Path to output folder>
```

To enable the generator to operate, the CSV file generated by JMeter must include certain required data which are correct by default in the last live version of JMeter.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#saveservice_requirements

You can copy the following configuration to your `user.properties` file in order to test the report generator.

[Sample configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#sample_configuration)

The report generation can be done as a stand alone process from a sample log file or automatically after running load test.

[Generating reports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report)